# Out of memory. InflateException Binary XML file Android

Tags: android, out-of-memory, android-inflate, inflate-exception

I have OutOfMemoryError while creating layout with a few images.

In line where logcat show me error i start declare TextView.

Error is on Samsung Galaxy S4.
When i run apps on HTC Desire X there is no error.

What might be the cause of that and how can i fix this.

```
10-21 18:32:19.243: E/dalvikvm-heap(20015): Out of memory on a 15822016-byte allocation.
10-21 18:32:19.243: I/dalvikvm(20015): "main" prio=5 tid=1 RUNNABLE
10-21 18:32:19.243: I/dalvikvm(20015):   | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x41d6cea0 self=0x41d5b538
10-21 18:32:19.243: I/dalvikvm(20015):   | sysTid=20015 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps handle=1074303316
10-21 18:32:19.243: I/dalvikvm(20015):   | state=R schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=235 stm=203 core=2
10-21 18:32:19.243: I/dalvikvm(20015):   at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
10-21 18:32:19.243: I/dalvikvm(20015):   at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:677)
10-21 18:32:19.243: I/dalvikvm(20015):   at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:507)
10-21 18:32:19.243: I/dalvikvm(20015):   at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:872)
10-21 18:32:19.243: I/dalvikvm(20015):   at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:3056)
10-21 18:32:19.243: I/dalvikvm(20015):   at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:602)
10-21 18:32:19.253: I/dalvikvm(20015):   at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3694)
10-21 18:32:19.263: I/dalvikvm(20015):   at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:898)
10-21 18:32:19.263: I/dalvikvm(20015):   at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:893)
10-21 18:32:19.263: I/dalvikvm(20015):   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
10-21 18:32:19.263: I/dalvikvm(20015):   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
10-21 18:32:19.263: I/dalvikvm(20015):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:600)
10-21 18:32:19.263: I/dalvikvm(20015):   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
10-21 18:32:19.263: I/dalvikvm(20015):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:675)
10-21 18:32:19.263: I/dalvikvm(20015):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:700)
10-21 18:32:19.263: I/dalvikvm(20015):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:761)
10-21 18:32:19.263: I/dalvikvm(20015):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:769)
10-21 18:32:19.263: I/dalvikvm(20015):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498)
10-21 18:32:19.263: I/dalvikvm(20015):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398)
10-21 18:32:19.263: I/dalvikvm(20015):   at com.example.fragments.LocalApiFragment.onCreateView(LocalApiFragment.java:40)
10-21 18:32:19.263: I/dalvikvm(20015):   at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1504)
10-21 18:32:19.263: I/dalvikvm(20015):   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:942)
10-21 18:32:19.263: I/dalvikvm(20015):   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1121)
10-21 18:32:19.263: I/dalvikvm(20015):   at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
10-21 18:32:19.263: I/dalvikvm(20015):   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1484)
10-21 18:32:19.263: I/dalvikvm(20015):   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:450)
10-21 18:32:19.263: I/dalvikvm(20015):   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
10-21 18:32:19.263: I/dalvikvm(20015):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
10-21 18:32:19.263: I/dalvikvm(20015):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
10-21 18:32:19.263: I/dalvikvm(20015):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5356)
10-21 18:32:19.263: I/dalvikvm(20015):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-21 18:32:19.263: I/dalvikvm(20015):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
10-21 18:32:19.263: I/dalvikvm(20015):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
10-21 18:32:19.263: I/dalvikvm(20015):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
10-21 18:32:19.263: I/dalvikvm(20015):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-21 18:32:19.263: D/skia(20015): --- allocation failed for scaled bitmap
10-21 18:32:19.263: D/AndroidRuntime(20015): Shutting down VM
10-21 18:32:19.263: W/dalvikvm(20015): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41d6bda0)
10-21 18:32:19.263: E/AndroidRuntime(20015): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-21 18:32:19.263: E/AndroidRuntime(20015): Process: com.example, PID: 20015
10-21 18:32:19.263: E/AndroidRuntime(20015): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #36: Error inflating class <unknown>
10-21 18:32:19.263: E/AndroidRuntime(20015):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:626)
10-21 18:32:19.263: E/AndroidRuntime(20015):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
10-21 18:32:19.263: E/AndroidRuntime(20015):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:675)
10-21 18:32:19.263: E/AndroidRuntime(20015):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:700)
10-21 18:32:19.263: E/AndroidRuntime(20015):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:761)
10-21 18:32:19.263: E/AndroidRuntime(20015):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:769)
10-21 18:32:19.263: E/AndroidRuntime(20015):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498)
10-21 18:32:19.263: E/AndroidRuntime(20015):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398)
10-21 18:32:19.263: E/AndroidRuntime(20015):    at com.example.fragments.LocalApiFragment.onCreateView(LocalApiFragment.java:40)
10-21 18:32:19.263: E/AndroidRuntime(20015):    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1504)
10-21 18:32:19.263: E/AndroidRuntime(20015):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:942)
10-21 18:32:19.263: E/AndroidRuntime(20015):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1121)
10-21 18:32:19.263: E/AndroidRuntime(20015):    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
10-21 18:32:19.263: E/AndroidRuntime(20015):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1484)
10-21 18:32:19.263: E/AndroidRuntime(20015):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:450)
10-21 18:32:19.263: E/AndroidRuntime(20015):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
10-21 18:32:19.263: E/AndroidRuntime(20015):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
10-21 18:32:19.263: E/AndroidRuntime(20015):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
10-21 18:32:19.263: E/AndroidRuntime(20015):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5356)
10-21 18:32:19.263: E/AndroidRuntime(20015):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-21 18:32:19.263: E/AndroidRuntime(20015):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
10-21 18:32:19.263: E/AndroidRuntime(20015):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
10-21 18:32:19.263: E/AndroidRuntime(20015):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
10-21 18:32:19.263: E/AndroidRuntime(20015):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-21 18:32:19.263: E/AndroidRuntime(20015): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
10-21 18:32:19.263: E/AndroidRuntime(20015):    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
10-21 18:32:19.263: E/AndroidRuntime(20015):    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
10-21 18:32:19.263: E/AndroidRuntime(20015):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:600)
10-21 18:32:19.263: E/AndroidRuntime(20015):    ... 23 more
10-21 18:32:19.263: E/AndroidRuntime(20015): Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
10-21 18:32:19.263: E/AndroidRuntime(20015):    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
10-21 18:32:19.263: E/AndroidRuntime(20015):    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:677)
10-21 18:32:19.263: E/AndroidRuntime(20015):    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:507)
10-21 18:32:19.263: E/AndroidRuntime(20015):    at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:872)
10-21 18:32:19.263: E/AndroidRuntime(20015):    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:3056)
10-21 18:32:19.263: E/AndroidRuntime(20015):    at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:602)
10-21 18:32:19.263: E/AndroidRuntime(20015):    at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3694)
10-21 18:32:19.263: E/AndroidRuntime(20015):    at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:898)
10-21 18:32:19.263: E/AndroidRuntime(20015):    at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:893)
10-21 18:32:19.263: E/AndroidRuntime(20015):    ... 26 more
```

Comment: Likely your bitmap is unreasonably large, at least for its color depth.

Answer (score 0):

Your bitmap is too heavy. Resize it(e.g gimp) and try again.

Comment: How it is possible when all my drawable resources occupy 2.5MB?

Comment: what is the resolution in px?

Comment: Background image is 1000x640, and every other is smaller.

When i put all images to folder drawable-nodpi apps run faster and there are no out of memory exception but some pictures are very small.

Should i create images in bigger resolution and put them in appropriate folders?

Answer (score 0):

I've stumble upon this problem too in most of HiDef devices such as Galaxy S4. It's because HiDef devices use xhdpi, xxhdpi and so on to inflate drawable. When they didn't find it, they scale it programmatically thus cause OutOfMemory Exception. So the solution is to put your drawable on those hdpi, xhdpi, xxhdpi, xxhdpi folder accordingly.

[samsung helpdesk source](http://helpdesk.metaio.com/questions/13296/samsung-galaxy-s4-ar-app-crashes.html)